# Distribute buttons (elements) evenly in columns

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have been trying to implement a keypad-like widget using bootstrap.

Here is a reconstruction of the problem at hand:

```
<div>
<div class="row">
    <span class="col-md-3">
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-warning">1</button>
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-warning">2</button>
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-warning">3</button>
    </span>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
    <span class="col-md-3">
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-warning btn-block">SPAN</button>
    </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem with this is that the buttons labelled 1, 2 and 3 are not spread out evenly to fill the 3 column width parent.

Now, I do know there is the `btn-group-justified` class that I can use, but it stretches the buttons to fit the width of the parent. What I want is to add fillers between the buttons.

Can that be accomplished using Bootstrap or should I use `display: table` or some weird voodoo code involving margins.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

How about a nested row?

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/XGb89/

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-4 text-center">
                <button class="btn btn-lg btn-warning">1</button>
            </div>
            ...
```

Comment: quite a voodoo code I would like to avoid, but it's like the only probable solution to this problem.

Comment: Voodoo? It's perfectly standard Bootstrap grid code. http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-nesting

Comment: Hmm, now that you have mentioned it, I think you're right! :)